# SQL Trigger Error update column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have created a trigger, that should update a field with value from another field. the data is being pulled from two tables.

Table 1 Columns(myTable);

```
name|subject|forward|goalie|Id
```

Table 2 Columns(MyTable2);

```
team|
```

My Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.[TriggerName]
ON dbo.myTable 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS BEGIN

    UPDATE t SET Subject =  
 t.Name + ' - ' + c.team + ' - '+ 
       CASE 
          WHEN t.new_forward = 1 THEN 'Forward,' ELSE '' 
       END + 
       ..........
       ..........
       ..........
       CASE 
          WHEN t.new_goalie = 1 THEN 'Goalie, ' ELSE ''
       END  
    FROM dbo.myTable t 
    INNER JOIN dbo.myTable2 c
    JOIN INSERTED i ON t.Id = i.Id

END
```

The error I get `The multi-part identifier t.Id could not be found`

What is wrong with my syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Are you missing a join condition on myTable2 c

Answer (score 1):

Per your own definition, the table `myTable` doesn't have a field called `Id`

> Table 1 Columns(myTable);

```
name|subject|forward|goalie
```

Without that field, your join of `JOIN INSERTED i ON t.Id = i.Id` is referring to a column that doesn't exist.